# Deleting part of an I/O file python

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to build a program that will record the name and grade of students in an I/O file. The issue is when the user removes a name from the file in the remove function. Thanks for taking a look :)

(x is a name given by the user)

```
    def remove(x):
    with open ("grades.txt", "rt") as f:
            text = f.read()

    if x in text:

            new = del text[x]
            with open ("grades.txt", "wt") as f:
                    text = f.write(new)

    else:
            print("name not in the file")
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How are you storing and what to remove? Be specific.

Comment: How exactly should `del text[x]` work? `x` is a string. You can't index a string by a string

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi don't edit white space in posts, especially ones about Python. White space is syntactically important in Python, and if the problem is with the WS itself, you will end up masking it.

Comment: @MattDMo I know Python. And by rolling back you introduced the error that I removed from the code.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi why are you removing errors from code in an edit? **DON'T**!

Comment: @MattDMo Oh. Got your point.

Comment: @S.Grym Please [edit] your question and put in a [mcve]. Please also include the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: This issue I had was specifically in the line del text[x].  I am intending to delete the name of the student in the file from this line however,  name 'shayla' is not defined, was the error that popped up. The file itself contains a string containing names inputted by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Since x and text are strings you first want to find the starting index of x in text.

```
if x in text:
    start_index = text.index(x)
    end_index = start_index + len(x)
    # so text[start_index:end_index] is x

    # Now to remove it:
    new = text[:start_index] + text[end_index:]
```

Edit:
Depending on how you store the names, you may need to remove a comma or newline as well.